# When I set the border radius, the color of the border is fade out, its looks buggy. How to solve this?

Tags: html, css, border-radius

I have created simple circles using border radius 50% but the color of border is fading means color is spread out. How to Solve this ?, I have tried to create border using ::after but that doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```css
.category-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.category-item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.image-box {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 24px;
  background: #FBF4F3;
  border: 1px solid #AF3D78;
}

.category-title {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="category-row">
  <div class="category-item">
    <div class="image-box"></div>
    <div class="category-title">Fragrance</div>
  </div>
  <div class="category-item">
    <div class="image-box"></div>
    <div class="category-title">Fragrance</div>
  </div>
  <div class="category-item">
    <div class="image-box"></div>
    <div class="category-title">Fragrance</div>
  </div>
  <div class="category-item">
    <div class="image-box"></div>
    <div class="category-title">Fragrance</div>
  </div>
  <div class="category-item">
    <div class="image-box"></div>
    <div class="category-title">Fragrance</div>
  </div>
```

[Here is my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZteO.png):

[image]

I want a smooth border color.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6oymkxbn/ Looks good to me

Comment: at first i am thinking this issue is about my screen resolution, i have tried in different screens but i have found same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be having problems with anti-aliasing on the circle's border. By creating a gradient effect by blending the border and background colors, anti-aliasing is a technique used to soften jagged edges. This occasionally results in the border colour looking faded or dispersed.

Creating the circle border using the **outline** property rather than the **border** property is one technique to fix this. Without changing the layout of the element or the content around it, the outline property draws a line outside the element's border edge.

CSS code:

```
  .image-box {
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto 24px;
  background: #FBF4F3;
  outline: 1px solid #AF3D78;
}
```

Comment: Outline also doesn't work well. Is there any other option ?

Answer (score 0):

Please open your jsfiddle link on a mobile device and zoom it. It is not fading out. The appearance may be different depending on the resolution and screen size.
Otherwise, you can try increasing the border-width to 2px:

```css
.category-row {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    .category-item {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding: 15px;
    }

    .image-box {
        width: 140px;
        height: 140px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: table;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto 24px;
        background: #FBF4F3;
        border: 2px solid #AF3D78;
    }

    .category-title {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="category-row">
    <div class="category-item">
        <div class="image-box"></div>
        <div class="category-title">Fragrance</div>
    </div>
    <div class="category-item">
        <div class="image-box"></div>
        <div class="category-title">Fragrance</div>
    </div>
    <div class="category-item">
        <div class="image-box"></div>
        <div class="category-title">Fragrance</div>
    </div>
    <div class="category-item">
        <div class="image-box"></div>
        <div class="category-title">Fragrance</div>
    </div>
    <div class="category-item">
        <div class="image-box"></div>
        <div class="category-title">Fragrance</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but i need border 1px only